# Replace abbreviations containing period in a string with abbrev with no periods in SAS

Tags: sas, substitution

I  have the following dataset and want to replace the last word if it is 'MD' or 'M.D.' or 'MD.' with 'MD'.

```
DATA EXAMPLE1;
  INPUT Names $char30.;
DATALINES;
AARON RAY, M.D.
AARON,RAY MD.
RAY,AARON,M.D.
PMD RAY ARON M.D
AARON MD RAY 
AARON RAY
;
run;
Data Convert;
Set Example1;
*I have used the following codes to address the different formats;

if scan(Names,-1,' ')=' MD. ' then Name_temp=tranwrd(Names,' MD. ',' MD ');
if scan(Names,-1,' ')=' M.D. ' then Name_temp=tranwrd(Names,' M.D. ',' MD ');
if scan(Names,-1,' ')='M.D.' then Name_temp=tranwrd(Names,'M.D.','MD');
if scan(Names,-1,' ')=',M.D.' then Name_temp=tranwrd(Names,',M.D.',' MD ');
if scan(Names,-1,' ')=' M.D.' then Name_temp=tranwrd(Names,' M.D.',' MD ');
if scan(Names,-1,' ')=' M.D ' then Name_temp=tranwrd(Names,' M.D ',' MD ');
run;
```

But only the first name is getting converted.

Let me know what I can do get this output

```
Obs              Names                         Name_temp

1              AARON RAY, M.D.             AARON RAY, MD
2              AARON,RAY MD.               AARON RAY, MD
3              RAY,AARON,M.D.              AARON RAY, MD
4              PMD RAY ARON M.D            AARON RAY, MD
5              AARON MD RAY
6              AARON RAY
```

Comment: Not sure simple code will get you the name_temps you show for obs #3 and #4.  #3 has name parts rearranged and #4 likewise while also discarding `PMD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of searching for every possible way `MD` could be spelled, standardize the last word to `MD` and search for that instead.

```
data want;
    set example1;

    last_word = scan(names, -1, ', ');

    if(compress(last_word, '. ') = 'MD') 
        then name_temp = tranwrd(names, strip(last_word), 'MD');
run;
```